# Is there any way to tell if an enemy is on overwatch?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I just lost an assault specialist because I didn't realize two enemies were on overwatch. Was there something I should have noticed that would have told me they were on overwatch?

Comment: Have an Assault trooper with Lightning Reflexes run past their field of fire. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm fairly early into the game but if an enemy is in view during their turn you can see when they go on overwatch. It pops up on the screen that the enemy has entered overwatch. I assume this is only for enemies in your view and that it doesn't constantly say it over their head thus forcing you to remember. I'll have to check somehow.

UPDATE: After playing the game for a while I've seen a lot of enemies go into overwatch. There is no way to tell they are in overwatch until they fire unless you see them. You need to remember what enemies are doing what.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I didn't remember seeing them go into overwatch at all. Maybe I just missed it.

Comment: I don't think it keeps an icon on them about it so I think you have to remember who is doing what. I'll check when I get off work in a few hours but I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's any persistent indication that an enemy is in overwatch, and you definitely can't tell if you don't have vision on that enemy when they enter it.
I've found that, on normal (ironman, though I doubt that makes a difference here), enemies seem to always spend their second turn, meaning if they didn't move twice they're probably in overwatch.  That or just assume any enemy who's been revealed but then went out of vision range is in overwatch.  Send your assault with Lightning Reflexes in first.

Answer (score 0):

If you've never seen the enemy they will not be on overwatch when you first see them; they have to move into cover (not necessarily for berserkers and floaters, but they still move). Otherwise, if you've seen one and they move back into fog, you can't tell if they are in overwatch unless you have sight, though if you wait a couple of turns that might give you a clue, but this is also not 100%.